# grep match lines with n leading spaces

Tags: grep, whitespace

I'm getting stuck on this one. I want to match all lines that start with exactly, say, 8 spaces and then a double quote mark.

```
cat file.txt | grep '[[:space:]]\{8\}"'
```

What am I doing wrong there? It's matching lines that start with more than 8 spaces also.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`cat file.txt | grep '^[[:space:]]\{8\}"'`

If you don't put `^`, it will match 8 spaces which is near to your `"`.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to pipe `cat` into `grep` just do `egrep '^ {8}"' file` the `^` character matches the start of the line so the pattern is anchored.

```
$ cat file
        "match"
        no match
   "no match"

$ egrep '^ {8}"' file
        "match"
```

The repetition quantifier `{n}` if part of the extended regular expression set so use `egrep` or alternatively use the `-E` option of `grep` to avoid escaping.